# Why isn't simple use of grep not coming up with any results?

Tags: grep

I used find to make a text file containing everything on an external hard drive that has the .mp3 and .wma extension. I wanted to try using grep on the file in order to view the files without the preceding directories (just the lines themselves, it will look less cluttered). However, when i type this:

```
grep -h "*.mp3" mp3sCIR.txt
```

nothing pops up. Yes, it's spelled correctly, and the file does actually contain the listing. I tried removing the -h and still nothing. Egrep works but does not suppress filename/path like requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you seem to be misunderstanding what the `-h` flag does.

`-h` will suppress the name(s) of the files passed on the command line (i.e. `mp3sCIR.txt` - although when only a single file is given, the name is not printed by default) - it won't remove anything from the names of the files *inside* the file.

Second, you are confusing shell patterns (aka 'globs') and regular expressions - grep uses regex syntax, so to match filenames with the `.mp3` extension you'd need<sup>1</sup>

```
grep ".*\.mp3" mp3sCIR.txt
```

(which should work the same with or without the `-E`, since the basic and extended forms are identical).

To remove the leading pathname components (i.e. what you were attemtping to do with `-h`) you could use

```
grep -o "[^/]*\.mp3"  mp3sCIR.txt
```

to print **o**nly the matching portion not including path separators, or with grep in perl compatible (PCRE) mode

```
grep -Po ".*/\K.*\.mp3" mp3sCIR.txt
```

For future reference, you could have *saved* the names without leading path components by using `find`'s `-printf '%f\n'` output format.

---

[1] Actually it seems like while BRE treats a bare `*` at the start of a pattern as literal, ERE (i.e. `egrep`/`grep -E`) appears to treat it as a quantifier for an empty expression ("zero or more instances of nothing"); hence `grep -E "*.mp3"` *does* match entries with the `.mp3` suffix - but not for the reason you'd probably think.

Comment: would you kindly tell me how i would use find's -printf argument in this instance? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @thinksinbinary something like `find path/to/dir \( -name '*.mp3' -o -name '*.wma' \) -printf '%f\n' > mp3s_wmas.txt`